# Sql count association frequency

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, psql

Given a 2-column table where there are always at least 2 occurrences of a value in the first column, and each distinct value in that column is matched to distinct values in the second column.
So like:

```
    X | AA
    X | BB
    Z | CC
    Z | BB
    Z | AA
    W | AA
    W | BB
    W | CC
```

How do you get the association frequency, or count, of pairs of values from the second column?
So taking the first table, you'd end up with something like:

```
    AA,BB | 3
    AA,CC | 2
    CC,BB | 2
```

Where the second column is a count of the occurrences of the first column pairs
 
oh and order does not matter, but should only occur once

```
    AA,BB = BB,AA
```

Comment: what have you tried? In stack overflow we're willing to help you come to a solution yourself, but we don't want to write your code for you :)

Comment: @TarynEast This is part of a larger problem. I don't know that I'll need to use this to solve it, but I'm curious to know if it can be done. But as far as answering this, my mind keeps throwing lower-level programming at me. Is it even possible in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the list of all combinations using a self-join:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col2 || ',' || t2.col2
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 < t2.col2;
```

You can then count them up:

```
select pairs, count(*)
from (select t.col1, t.col2, t.col2 || ',' || t2.col2 as pairs
      from table t join
           table t2
           on t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 < t2.col2
     ) p
group by pairs;
```

Comment: Dunno, why but didn't think that was possible.
But it does make a lot of sense, actually thinking it through, thanks! Oh buta while I used numbers to make it easier to read, it's actually string|string. So the < operator can't work, though that's a really neat trick!
I'll update it now.

Comment: Damn, was just about to come here and say never mind, I'm dumb, and mark your answer. Least I can still do one of them!